# MFMailComposeViewController in react native on expo

Tags: react-native, expo, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

My Goal is to open up the mail modal natively in expo managed workflow on dont want to redirect to the mail app.

This is the code for just open the mail app:

```
onPress{() => {
     Linking.openURL("mailto:support@myApp.com");
}}
```

There is no package or option from expo and I cant use [react-native-mail](https://github.com/chirag04/react-native-mail) because it contains native code and this doesnt work in expo managed workflow.

Is there another option to get this functionality in expo managed workflow?

Versions:
react: 16.13.1
react-native: 0.63.2
expo: ^40.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/mail-composer/

this uses `MFMailComposeViewController` on iOS: https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/master/packages/expo-mail-composer/ios/EXMailComposer/EXMailComposer.m